# Highlighting a cell PHP a certain color based on MYSQL value

Tags: php, mysql, css

I have three values that can be displayed from a **table/column in mysql**, RED, GREEN, YELLOW for the field "ProspectStatus"

Is there anyway I can make a cell change its background color based on the value?

e.g.

```
echo "<td>" . $row['ProspectStatus'] . "</td>";
```

PHP Code:

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customerdetails"); 
//List the Columns for the Report 
echo "<table border='1'> 
<tr> 
<th>CustomerID</th> 
<th>Customer Name</th> 
<th>Prospect Status</th> 
<th>Address</th> 
</tr>"; 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  { 
  echo "<tr>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $row['CustomerID'] . "</td>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $row['CustomerName'] . "</td>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $row['ProspectStatus'] . "</td>"; //this is the field I want to show either RED, GREEN or YELLOW 
  echo "<td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>"; 
  echo "</tr>"; 
  } 
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36716586/how-to-change-cell-color-of-table-based-on-information-stored-in-database-table can anybody please help out how solve above problem ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  { 
  echo "<tr>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $row['CustomerID'] . "</td>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $row['CustomerName'] . "</td>"; 
  if($row['ProspectStatus']=='[val1]') // [val1] can be 'approved'
         echo "<td style='background-color: #00FF00;'>".$row['ProspectStatus']."</td>"; 
  else if($row['ProspectStatus']=='[val2]')// [val2]can be 'rejected'
         echo "<td style='background-color: #FF0000;'>".$row['ProspectStatus']."</td>"; 
  else if($row['ProspectStatus']=='[val3]') //[val3] can be 'on hold'
         echo "<td style='background-color: #FFFF00;'>".$row['ProspectStatus']."</td>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>"; 
  echo "</tr>"; 
  } 
echo "</table>";
```

The value of the status may depend on the color. I assume that `val1`, `val2` and `val3` are the values of the 3 colors.

Comment: I quite like this answer, and it works pretty good for Yellow & Green, however RED does not work. I assume its because of '[RED]'

Comment: Glad it help. And you can change the colors into html codes like red = #FF0000, yellow = #FFFF00 and green = #00FF00. You can accept this as an answer though. I'll edit this for you.

Comment: You had an opportunity here to address poor coding practices used by a newcomer and instead you posted a sloppy solution like this. Sad.

Comment: It is pointless to argue with such coding conventions. Nevertheless, I answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

**First, use CSS for this, not messy in-line style definitions**

The most maintainable option would probably separate the color codes themselves from the view logic, so in CSS, create some new classes:

```
td.done { background-color: green; }
td.working { background-color: yellow; }
td.stopped { background-color: red; }
```

Then, in your loop just do this (you don't need the echo statements, anything outside of `<?` and `?>` tags will be parsed as HTML rather than PHP):

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
<tr>
    ....
    <td class='<?= $row['ProspectStatus']; ?>'><?= $row['ProspectStatus']; ?></td>
    ....
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

This way, if `ProspectStatus` is 'done', the cell will have a green background, if it's 'working', it will have a yellow background and if it's stopped it will have a red background.

**If ProspectStatus is a range, or otherwise not this simple**

Let's say `ProspectStatus` doesn't have `done`, `working` and `stopped` or similar simple values, and instead it's a range, for this you can use a simple nested ternary operator to get the color you want instead of `<tr class='<?= $row['ProspectStatus']; ?>'>`:

```
<tr class='<?php echo ($row['ProspectStatus'] >= 80) ? "done" : (($row['ProspectStatus'] >= 40) ? "working" : "stopped"); ?>'>
```

With this one liner, if `ProspectStatus` is greater than 80, the field will be green, if it's between 40 and 80 it will be yellow and if it's below 40 it will be red.

**Note: `mysql_` functions are DEPRECATED**

By using the `mysql_` features, you run the risk of your program not working in future versions of PHP as those functions have been formally deprecated as of 5.5.

The new recommended way to perform your query is this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("username","password","hostname","password");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM customerdetails");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())...
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok lets say you have to reference the value of `ProspectStatus`, Then you have to create a new CSS class? Same maintainability issue whereas you can do it inline. Thank you for your constructive criticism.

Comment: @ChristianMark How is it the same maintainability issue? In real-world programming, views change a lot more often than business logic. If he uses this same data (or another piece of data that uses red/yellow/green backgrounds) he can re-use the `red`, `green` and `yellow` classes and when he wants to change display logic, he only has to change it in one place.

Comment: @ChristianMark - I have similar things in production code, I tend to use a nested ternary inline to choose which class to display, like what I put under 'If XYZ is a range...'

Answer (score 0):

Create a `class` of the color you want for that cell and then make an `if` statement that will check the value. Depending on the value, echo that `class`.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add it to you Table data tag like below

The following code will work:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  { 
  echo "<tr style='background-color: ". $row['ProspectStatus'] ."'>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $row['CustomerID'] . "</td>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $row['CustomerName'] . "</td>"; 
  echo "<td>" . $row['ProspectStatus'] . "</td>"; //this is the field I want to show either RED, GREEN or YELLOW 
  echo "<td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>"; 
  echo "</tr>"; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<tr style='background-color: ". $row['ProspectStatus'] ."'>";
```

or make an if statement checking what color || then displaying the echo

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you want to change the color of only one particular cell, this should do the trick:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
      { 
      echo "<tr>"; 
      echo "<td>" . $row['CustomerID'] . "</td>"; 
      echo "<td>" . $row['CustomerName'] . "</td>"; 
      echo "<td  style='background-color: ". $row['ProspectStatus'] ."'>" . $row['ProspectStatus'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['Address'] . "</td>"; 
      echo "</tr>"; 
      }
```