# how to change row font color or background color base on values in PHP json im using bootgrid

Tags: php, json, row

THIS IS MY PHP CODE how can i changed the font color of specific row based on the value

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employee "; $sqlTot .= $sql; $sqlRec .= $sql;

    if(isset($where) && $where != '') {
        $sqlTot .= $where;
        $sqlRec .= $where;
    }

    if ($rp!=-1)
    $sqlRec .= " LIMIT ". $start_from .",".$rp;

    $qtot = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sqlTot) or die("error to fetch tot seaman's data");
    $queryRecords = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sqlRec) or die("error to fetch seaman's data");

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryRecords) ) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

        $json_data = array(
            "current"            => intval($params['current']),
            "rowCount"            => 10,
            "total"    => intval($qtot->num_rows),
            "rows"            => $data   // total data array
        );

        return $json_data;
    }
```

Comment: Your code is wrong. It has an unnecessary end bracket. Are there some lines of code code missing?

Comment: yes cause it is only a part of a code where i want to make  the row font color or background color change base on the value

Comment: It's a frontend task and PHP cannot set background color or any related things to this.

Comment: like for example i have $row['remarks']='ACTIVE' iwant to make it green color

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlighting a cell PHP a certain color based on MYSQL value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462388/highlighting-a-cell-php-a-certain-color-based-on-mysql-value)

Answer (score 0):

Add more details about your client-side code. according to comments, you can change your code to this one:

```
...
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryRecords) ) {
    if ($you_want)
        $row['remarks'] = 'ACTIVE';
    $data[] = $row;
}
...
```

Comment: what is if($you_want)

Comment: It's a boolean variable that indicates which rows must be remarked as active.